# Fabricjs paths not rendering until mouseup

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, requestanimationframe

After creating and animating a spritesheet image into a [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/) (1.5) canvas by calling

```
(function render() {
  self.fabricCanvas.renderAll();
  fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
})();
```

when trying to *freeDraw* new [paths](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Path.html) these are only rendered `onmouseup`.

Why is this and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not clear about what version of fabricjs are you using.

renderAll function is cleaning the upperCanvas layer, where the drawing happens.

When you release the mouse button a path gets created and added to the canvas like other objects. Since that moment the renderAll is going to render also your newly created path, while before it was just clearing the surface where you were drawing it.

Here on the issue tracker of fabricjs there is notice of the same behaviour

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2723

fix:

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/2895

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi, I've edited my question to specify fabricjs v1.5. I didn't know that was the way fabricjs created paths. I understand now. Still don't know what the solution may be.

Comment: 1) update to 1.6.0, 2) please in the issue tracker there is already an issue about this situation, could you search it and add that you have same problem? thanks.

Comment: Oh, I thought 1.5 was the latest because of the CDN link at the bottom of the page. I'll update, thanks. I can't find the issue you said thoug. Could you just post the link please?

Comment: Oh, so you are the developer behind fabricjs! Nice, cool lib. Still same issue with v1.6 btw

Comment: Haven't found the issue you mentioned either. Could you edit your answer and post the link, please?

Comment: Uploaded fix now, but you have to build the lib from the github, or wait some days i rebuild it. Or just copy the fix in your file, is very small. one https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/2895 see the changed file.

Comment: Thanks @andreabogazzi. It does work now with the proposed change.

Comment: I think you should post your last comment in the form of an answer so I can select it as the correct one.